# Como criar uma arvore em XML com atributos utilizando o LINQ

Tags: c#

Boa noite!
Como faço para criar um documento XML com atributos utilizando o LINQ to XML

EX:

```
<class name="Pessoa" tabela="pessoa">
    <property name="id" column="id" pk="true"/>
    <property name="nome" column="nome"/>
    <property name="genero" column="genero"/>
    <property name="dataNasc" column="data_nasc" type="date"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito sua pergunta pois não tem como utilizar linq para geral um xml... linq e para acesso a dados de uma determinada coleção, no exemplo abaixo utilizamos XElement e XAttribute para nos ajudar com isso.

Mas acredito que esse link [Creating XML Trees in C# (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx) será usual.

Para criar atributos utilize XAttribute, elementos XElement.

```
var obj = new[]
{    
 new {ID = 1, Nome= "A", Fone = "999999999"},    
 new {ID = 2, Nome= "B", Fone = "125125125},    
 new {ID = 3, Nome= "C", Fone = "346346345"},    
 new {ID = 4, Nome= "D", Fone = "568658568"}  

};

XElement _cliente= new XElement("customers",
                    from c in obj
                    orderby c.ID //descending 
                    select new XElement("customer",
                        new XElement("name", c.Nome),
                        new XAttribute("ID", c.ID),
                        new XElement("telefone", c.Fone)
                                        )
                                );

Console.WriteLine(_cliente);
```